# How can I install a printer driver from a (local) ppd file?

Tags: drivers, printing

I've selected the *local* option and I have had this screen

[image]

in front of me for a good 10 minutes now. Am I doings omething wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a network printer via

```
http://localhost:631
```

leads to a window where one can select a (local) .ppd file to install printer.